# pass in date and get first and last date of that month?

Tags: asp.net, datetime

I have a date stored in a session variable, I then convert it to a date. Now I want to get the first and last date of the month for the date that is passed.

```
DateTime tempDate = System.Convert.ToDateTime(Session["Diary_Date"]);
DateTime startOfMonth = //what goes here?
DateTime endOfMonth = //??
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do this:

```
DateTime startOfMonth = new DateTime(tempDate.Year, tempDate.Month, 1);
DateTime endOfMonth = startOfMonth.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way is

```
DateTime startOfMonth = new DateTime(tempDate.Year, tempDate.Month, 1);
DateTime endOfMonth = new DateTime(tempDate.Year, tempDate.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(tempDate.Year, tempDate.Month));
```

Comment: +1 strange, why have i always used `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetDaysInMonth` instead?